# Raster classification

Tags: arcgis-desktop, reclassify

I am a novice in arcgis.

Initially I had a raster of land use with several classes which I used a neural network model to predict future land use based on one class which is agriculture, in the study area. Processing the raster using arcmap and the neural network finally gave me a raster with the predicted future land use scenario with two classes (the one being modelled =1, and the remaining land use which the model classified as 0). Now I want to revert back to a raster with the original classes (of course including the agriculture that has changed).

These are images of the two rasters.

[image]

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjYlt.png)

Comment: There is only one image...

Comment: Assuming your agriculture class is stored as 3, Con(result==1,3, original) expression in raster calculator will suffice.